# Word Automation: Noneditable

Tags: ms-access, vba, automation, ms-word, ms-office

I am using Access to send data to a template I created in Word. After it succesfully sends the data I need to make the open Word Document NON-editable.

Also, I notice that after I am done with the Document it prompts to save. Is it possible to remove this prompt, BUT allow the capability to save.

This is the code I am using to do the Word Automation:

```
' Create a Word document from template.
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim strTemplateLocation As String
Dim myVariable As String
myVariable = “TEST!!”

' Specify location of template
strTemplateLocation = Left(CurrentDb.Name, InStrRev(CurrentDb.Name, "\")) & "test.dot"

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

WordApp.Visible = True
WordApp.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
WordApp.Documents.Add Template:=strTemplateLocation, NewTemplate:=False


' Replace each bookmark with field contents.
WordApp.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="myBookmark"
WordApp.Selection.TypeText myVariable

DoEvents
WordApp.Activate
Set WordApp = Nothing
```

Comment: It's much easier to make suggestions if you show your actual code.  Otherwise we all have to guess how you're currently doing it.

Comment: Does this even compile ?  Looking at Dim myVariable = "TEST!!"...

Answer (score 1):

The `Document` object has a `Saved` property which normally changes to `False` if any changes are made. If you set this property to `True` then you won't be prompted to save the document when you close it but you can still save it manually (via `Save` or `Save As...`) if you want to.

You can use the `Protect` method of the `Document` object to restrict the changes which the user can make. For example, you can call it with the parameter `wdAllowOnlyReading` which will mean that no changes of any kind can be made. You may also need to look at password protecting the document to prevent the user from simply unprotecting it again

Comment: Is this on the Access side or Word? Can you provide the full statement? Thanks.

Comment: tried the statement in Access "WordApp.ActiveWindow.Document.Protect" but get argument not optional error message

Comment: @Rick: Umm... that's because `Protect` has an argument that is not optional, and you didn't give that argument any value. If you hit the spacebar after `.Protect` then intellisense should show this. Or just read Word VBA help for `Protect`. It's all explained in there.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need.  Tested from Excel, not Access, so you'll need to fix the template path

```
Sub Tester()
    ' Create a Word document from template.
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim strTemplateLocation As String
    Dim myVariable As String

    myVariable = "TEST!!"
    ' Specify location of template
    strTemplateLocation = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.dotx"
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    With WordApp
        .Visible = True
        .WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
        .Documents.Add Template:=strTemplateLocation, NewTemplate:=False

        ' Replace each bookmark with field contents.
        .Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="myBookmark"
        .Selection.TypeText myVariable

        DoEvents

        With .ActiveDocument
            .Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyReading, Password:="blah"
            .Saved = True
        End With

        .Activate
    End With

    Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried WordApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone but it doesn't seem to work. Don't really want to save it via automation. I need it to open and not be allowed to be edited. The save message appears when I close the Word Document. Eitherway couldn't find the ReadOnlyRecommended parameter.

Comment: Tried WordApp.ActiveWindow.Document.ReadOnly in Access and get the error message: "Invalid use of property".

Comment: @Rick: That's because the `ReadOnly` property is (ironically) read-only. You can't set it, you can only check its status. Are you aware that VBA has a help file? I just learned all this by pressing F1.